# How to use Rx.Observable.fromEvent in an element that does not exist in the DOM yet?

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

With regular JS and Jquery you can do something like `$(document).on('click', '#id', function () { // whatever })`. This allows us to add an event in a element that may not exist in the DOM yet. I would like to use `Rx.Observable.fromEvent(ele, 'click')` to do the same - I need to do that because the elements are being created in another stream. Is this possible?

---

**CONTEXT**

Some context of what I am trying to achieve. I'm following [The introduction to Reactive Programming you've been missing](https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754). The proposed exercise is:

1. Fetch users from GitHub API
2. Display three users as suggestions to follow;
3. Each user should have a "remove" button;
4. Whenever a remove button is clicked, remove that suggestion and load another one from the buffer;

It goes very well until the part of loading the three suggestions. For example:

```
Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent($('#refresh'), 'click')
    .startWith('start up click')
    .map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 500))
    .map(offset => `${GITHUB_API}?since=${offset}`)
    .map(url => jQuery.getJSON(url))
    .flatMap(promisse => Rx.Observable.from(promisse))
    .map(users => users.slice(0, 3))
    .do(_ => $('#users').empty())
    .flatMap(users => users)
    .map(user => createItem(user))
    .subscribe(user => $('#users').append(user));

// Just an example for creating the elements
function createItem(user, idx) {
  return $(`
    <li class="item-wrapper horizontal" >
      <img src="${user.avatar_url}" class="rounded-circle" width="50" height="50">

      <div class="item-infos-wrapper vertical">
        <span class="font-weight-bold">${user.login}</span>
        <span class="font-weight-normal">What can we put in here?</span>
      </div>

      <button id="close${idx}" type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-sm item-action">remove</button>
    </li>
  `);
}
```

From what I understood of the aforementioned article, the idea to handle the item removal is to use `combineLatest` with a stream of "remove button clicked" and "requestStream" (containing the results of the API), feeding the combined data in the pipe that creates the elements. My current problem is build this retro feeding from the remove button clicked stream plus request stream into the consumer that creates the elements.

Comment: Can you get a stream of the created elements? You could do something like `clicks$ = createdElements$.pipe(mergeMap(element => fromEvent(element, 'click')));`

Comment: Hi @Andrew, I've updated the question with the context in which I am in. I think that doing what you mention would cause a cycle in my current logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this but it's not clear to me where `idx` comes from. Is it a property of the user?

```
Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent($('#refresh'), 'click')
    .startWith('start up click')
    .map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 500))
    .map(offset => `${GITHUB_API}?since=${offset}`)
    .map(url => jQuery.getJSON(url))
    .flatMap(promisse => Rx.Observable.from(promisse))
    .map(users => users.slice(0, 3))
    .do(_ => $('#users').empty())
    .flatMap(users => users)
    .map(user => createItem(user)) //at this point we have a listItem in the stream

    // from this point it's changed

    .tap(listItem => $('#users').append(listItem)) //append to users, but keep the listItem in the stream
    .map(listItem => $(listItem).find('button')[0]) //get the button element
    .mergemMap(closeButton => fromEvent(closeButton, 'click')) //subscribe to click on the button and merge all the clicks into one stream
    .subscribe((event: MouseEvent) => {
        console.log('clicked', event); //a close button was clicked...
    });
```

and here is a way of removing the `li` when the button is clicked:

```
Rx.Observable
    .fromEvent($('#refresh'), 'click')
    .startWith('start up click')
    .map(() => Math.floor(Math.random() * 500))
    .map(offset => `${GITHUB_API}?since=${offset}`)
    .map(url => jQuery.getJSON(url))
    .flatMap(promisse => Rx.Observable.from(promisse))
    .map(users => users.slice(0, 3))
    .do(_ => $('#users').empty())
    .flatMap(users => users)
    .mergeMap(user => {
        const listItem = createItem(user);
        $('#users').append(listItem);

        const closeButton = $(listItem).find('button')[0];
        return Rx.Observable.fromEvent(closeButton, 'click').first().tap(_ => listItem.remove());
    })
    .subscribe();
```

Comment: `idx` was an experiment I was doing. I can safely replace it with `user.login` that is unique for each user. I tested your code and it works great for adding the event in all buttons, I am not sure if I will be able to evolve it to do the retro feeding I mention in the question, but it worths trying already! Thank you very much!

Comment: @HumbleStudent You're welcome. I also added a snippet for removing the listItem when click is pressed. You can also update it to remove all the listItems when you unsubscribe...

Comment: Tested and it works like a charm! I am impressed of how much can be done with so little code. Next challenge is to load a new item when one of them is removed :)